# How to deal with new users that don't accept answers for their questions?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, new-users, etiquette

Here's the [subject of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1727801/devnegikec).

This is a newish user that I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23215534/57475) for a little while ago. His response was "*thanks it works for me now*", to which I advised him that he could mark the answer if it was helpful.

After some while had passed and I was reviewing activity, I noticed he didn't respond so I took a look at his stats and other questions.

Discovered he has:

- Asked 4 question
- Not accepted any answers
- 2 of them have answers with comments that state that the answer solved the problem
- One of them has no answers but has a comment that states it is fixed and no longer an issue.

I've tried to advise the user to mark answers where appropriate, to which he has neither acted or responded. I've flagged [one to close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907510) as the problem is no longer an issue.

Is there anything else that should/could be done or is this appropriate?

---

After spending a chunk of time on answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520429/convert-numeric-values-to-feet-and-inches-in-ui-slider), I found another great example of a **[user with a zero accept rate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1887931/arun-singh)**:

- Asked 22 questions
- Not accepted any answers

Comment: This is not appropriate but I don't think there's something can be done. We cannot force him to accept the answer (unless it's a bounty) but we can learn not to answer his questions in the future if he shows no politeness.

Comment: Related: [Correcting askers who do not follow up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195144)

Comment: @JoshCaswell I was referring to completing the cycle of ask a question and close it off by marking the answer but have amended it to reduce any confusion

Comment: I would say that it is desired for questioners to accept correct answers so others know that there is an answer solving the problem and which one it is. But of course nobody else than the questioner himself can do it. So to encourage more one could send regular reminders if there are questions with unaccepted answers and also when new questions are asked links to the old unaccepted questions with answers (probably it is already like this?).

Comment: @Cupcake not really related as the user in this case commented on answers to say they solved the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You "deal" with them by ignoring the fact that they've not accepted any answers. Don't look at their history, don't look at their other questions. Just concentrate on the **question** not the **asker**.

Users are under no obligation to accept an answer, despite the fact that accepting an answer shows that the problem is solved (at least to the OP's satisfaction).

In some ways a question without an accepted answer has a clearer "correct" answer as the highest voted answer will (under the default answer sorting rules) appear directly under the question.

Comment: Ignoring could be a bit difficult in practice. Should I look at a questioners history before looking at his/her newest question?

Comment: @Trilarion It shouldn't be about rep; it should be about helping the user... at least in the definition of what this site is for.

Comment: I see your point but it's just basic manners and it completes the process if your problem is solved.

Comment: @Tanner - Yes it is basic manners, but life's too short to be badgering people about it.

Comment: Beyond basic manners it's also a value for the site, knowing there is an reference answer that very likely solves the question.

Comment: @Trilarion nope. The votes indicate that. The check mark is only the OP's satisfaction. Most of the time the OP accepts an answer having no idea which on is actually the correct and the best... they do accept whatever solves their issue and not what the best answer is. Remeber, this only happens most of the time...

Comment: @Trilarion [here's a perfect example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811526/exporting-pivot-table-in-ms-access-to-excel-with-c-sharp). The OP decides to accept the answer even though he has no idea whether the answer is helpful or not as he indicates in the comments section below the answer.

Comment: Actually, if the acceptance of an answer means so little, I find the visual size of the acceptance answer mark too big for the meaning it really has. I guess users put a bit more trust in the check mark than is justified.

Comment: @Trilarion that's a whole different discussion. Check Meta Stack Exchange as well as here for *lots* more discussion on that.

Comment: I had the same problem and your answer is not satisfying, the answerer put some time to help the asker and get no reward, reputation is important, for example for one who is banned from asking new question because his answers and questions hasn't received any vote or score

Comment: I have the same problem right now. My answer is correct, but the questioner won't accept it because it is unhappy with the facts (the template language syntax don't work the way he wishes) so he's penalizing me for showing him a workaround. I feel like a moderator should be able to accept the answer on another users behalf.

Comment: There's an use case that gets repeated often. A new user joins SoF and asks a question. The question gets answered, the user thanks and leaves. I think in this case it should be legit for a moderator to mark the answer as accepted (after some time). The OP has clearly expressed her satisfaction with an answer. You may say an answer's reputation tells a solution worked, but SoF clearly makes a difference between accepted and not accepted answers. As questions with an accepted answer are painted green, only with the glimpse of an eye you can tell a question has a valid working solution.

Comment: ...im also frustrated by this practice. I've solved a lot of questions from Nooobs - and like 90% of them miss to accept my working answer which fixes their issue. This is rather frustrating, as there is not even a possibility of mentioning or messaging those noob-users about it. 

They just don't know that they *SHOULD* accept a answer if it answeres their question. I think SO should do something about it.. like reminding new users that they should accept an answer if their issue got solved.

After all: thats how SO gets better: with answers that work and are also marked as working.