# Upvote answers where new users don't accept them themselves

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, new-users, upvotes

There is this common problem that we face when answering new users' questions: they don't upvote/accept answers, even if they comment on them that "it worked". (Which is why this was raised as a "problem" for several times now on meta: some examples: [#1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302669/lots-of-users-dont-accept-any-answers), [#2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254797/how-to-deal-with-new-users-that-dont-accept-answers-for-their-questions), [#3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on), and perhaps some more).

What I would like to address here is the lack of rewarding for the user who put efforts into giving the proper answer.

My suggestion to do so is to create an algorithm like:

- Non experienced user<sup>1</sup> asked question
- Non experienced user received answer
- Non experienced user commented some key words like (worked, thanks, awesome, etc.)
- Non experienced user doesn't act in any other way on the question for 24 hours (I mean upvote, downvote or accept)
- Answer has 0 score (no more, no less)

If these conditions are met, then I propose one for these two options:

1. Either [Community ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) robot upvotes automatically;
2. Or we implement a SObot who posts in [the SOBotics chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) that the answer might be worthy of an upvote. In this case I think a moderator can both upvote and leave the usual: "accept the answer" comment for the OP.

---

<sup>1</sup> We can define *Non experienced user* and refine the definition over time (or perhaps this was established already) but for a lack of such a definition I suggest to start with:

1. A new account (no more than 24 hours),
2. or is a user who just posted their first question (and didn't post any answers),
3. or is a user who had lots of questions but the upvote/accept rate is very small, to 0, indicating he/she doesn't know that this should be done.

Comment: If the answer is actually helpful it will be auto upvoted. If it's not then no.

Comment: (by other more experienced users)

Comment: Then it's probably not helpful. Most questions from new users (**not all**) are obvious dupes, and they should not answer at all.

Comment: I'd say a better solution to solve this problem is when a new user posts such a comment, a popup is shown with information about accepting answers and not posting thanks comments. Your proposal seems a bit complicated and strange.

Comment: @user202729 In low-traffic tags, upvotes on actually helpful answers are pretty rare.

Comment: Then it's **their** fault to not read the help center/documentation/popup. Well, if the behavior continues people won't keep answering their questions. Problem solved.

Comment: (I disagreed with the proposal and downvoted)

Comment: ... Well, it's true that popularity affects votes, but if the answers are useful to at least one user, they will upvote that.

Comment: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980168/how-to-save-as-a-new-file-and-keep-working-on-the-original-one-in-vim).

Comment: _"Good answer! But this didn't worked for me :-("_ <-- How'd an algorithm detect that typo properly?

Comment: Marking an answer as accepted is never mandatory and has an entirely different meaning from voting. Answers should aim to be helpful to future visitors too; if they are then they’ll end up getting voted up over time. There is no problem here that needs solving.

Comment: I'd just like to say, as a RO of SOBotics, that I wouldn't be comfortable with having a bot that posts this kind of information into the room. We are about moderating content on the site and flagging accordingly in an attempt to keep SO clean. That's our motive. We stay away from votes and I don't see that changing any time soon. Furthermore, the people within the room all share the same view of keeping SO clean. Implementing this kind of bot may (likely will) cause disagreements between our members.

Comment: @Adelin, Well or we can just ignore the fact op don't accept, upvote or simply disapear in the void. Everyting involving automatic upvote should be a no-no. and I don't see how it will help. Perhaps the bot should track op adress based on IP and other Oauth2 token. Then we send a team of nice guy?

Comment: @Adelin It seems that you think that effort on the answerers part, no matter how bad a question might be, should be rewarded. That's completely backwards. We value correctness, reusability and extraordinary understanding of a problem, so that others can in turn understand better. That you invest twenty hours or ten seconds is completely irrelevant. A subject expert will produce a highly valuable answers in mere seconds when addressing a problem they master, whereas a novice would take three hours to explain it with flaws. Should the novice answer be rewarded just because they "tried hard"?

Comment: More succinctly: this is not a day-camp. If you want reward for your efforts, go post original meme dumps on imgur, they'll recognize effort where it's due.

Answer (score 20):

No, this is not going to happen. You misunderstand what accepting an answer is for.

Marking an answer as accepted is purely a sign that the OP found a specific answer the most helpful. It is never required to mark an answer as accepted.

Voting on the other hand is used by the whole community to indicate how helpful and applicable an answer is. Answers should aim to be useful to a wider audience; they should be helpful to anyone be that has the same problem to solve, visiting the question at some point in the future.

So a good answer will, *over time* get upvoted anyway. It doesn’t matter what the original asker thinks about the answer, the wider community decides this.

When a good answer doesn’t get marked as accepted (either because the asker is inexperienced or doesn’t think the answer deserved to be marked), *that doesn’t matter*. Stack Overflow aims to help the many, not (just) the individual question asker.

There is no problem with not accepting, so there is no problem here that needs solving.

Comment: @Adelin so ask yourself: was my answer helpful to more people? Is the question clear, with a good concise problem description? Is this a problem more people will have, and they can find this post? If the answer is yes to all three, then console yourself that one example doesn’t make a pattern, and it’s all just fake points.

Comment: @Adelin: "*2 years later and myself, as a contributor, gained 0 from this effort (except the warm fuzzy feeling that I helped OP), so I still don't agree that there is no problem here that needs solving.*" ... Even ignoring the "quality" of your answer, if getting upvotes and accepts is why you're answering questions, maybe this isn't the place for you.

Comment: @Adelin: Providing good content is the goal. Reputation is *gratitude*. Not everybody expresses gratitude, but that shouldn't stop you from doing the right thing.

Comment: @Adelin all this with the *effort* again. When in the world did you get the idea that any of this was about effort? We don't reward for the effort. Effort has nothing to do with writing a good answer. Effort is not what one should be looking forward to do when interacting with SO. You can put great effort into a total mess of an answer. Effort is not the characteristic through which it is possible to correctly evaluate rewards in the game of Stack Overflow. I will not stop. Effort is not something we have to reward. Effort is orthogonal to result and correctness.

Comment: @Adelin: "*if you’re rewarding someone for their efforts*" That's why I called reputation "gratitude", not a "reward". A reward would be based on some objective measurement of the quality of the service provided. Gratitude is not; it is given or not as each individual sees fit, in accord with their own subjective standards. No answer is *owed* reputation. No answer, however much you like it, however much "effort" you put into it, is owed an upvote or an accept checkmark. I hope you don't help people just to hear them say "thank you". Rep is the same way.

Answer (score 4):

Automatic upvoting in such a manner would be a poor trade-off. It would, in exchange for eliminating the occasional annoyance of helpful answers not bringing in reputation, introduce a systemic content curation problem. You suggest two implementation options:

> Either Community ♦ robot upvotes automatically;

Which means the system would endorse answers with no oversight, disregarding the possibility of false positives or misjudgements by the OP about the value of the answer.

> Or we implement a SObot who posts in the SOBotics chat that the answer might be worthy of an upvote. In this case I think a moderator can both upvote and leave the usual: "accept the answer" comment for the OP.

Which means we'd have to recruit uninvolved (and possibly uninterested and lacking knowledge of the subject matter) users to perform this additional curation duty. (See also [this comment by Bugs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364132/upvote-answers-where-new-users-dont-accept-them-themselves#comment562394_364132).)